# Program for viewing MATLAB figures without MCR library

Tags: matlab, interactive, viewer, figure

I need to send a 3D .fig file to someone without access to MATLAB. I've already compiled an executable that will open a MATLAB figure, but it requires the MCR library to be installed, and the user does not have admin rights on their computer. Is there a simple program out there that can open a .fig file and allow the user to rotate/zoom/etc. without the MATLAB environment?

The alternative solution I've thought of would be to [use an animated GIF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21944-animated-gif) to transition between a few views, but I'd rather allow the user to select their own views with an interactive plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without a compiled application or MATLAB as of 5/20/2010

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it wasn't the one I wanted to hear. :) I guess it's time to figure out how to make those GIFs.